# How to do Semantic Segmentation using Unsupervised learning

Tags: python, image-segmentation, unsupervised-learning

I'm the master of mechanical engineering student.My professor required me to do Semantic Segmentation using Unsupervised learning to achieve image recognition for autonomous driving.
I study a lot theory but I don't know how to implement the code...
I hope who can teach me how to do Semantic Segmentation using Unsupervised learning... thanks a lot.

I ever tried to do some repository form github but all failed.Maybe I'm  rookie that don't understand the step from ReadMe...

Comment: You need to use a CNN model such as U-Net, DeepLabv3Plus, etc. depending on your use case. U-Net can help, I think. I used DeepLabv3Plus (https://www.kaggle.com/code/hserdaraltan/grouping-products-by-pattern-design) but that was segmentation for clothing. Just to give you an idea. You can start with U-Net.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]